# For which $p\in [1,+\infty]$ is the following operator continuous?

Tags: operator-theory, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

For each $n\in \Bbb N$, $n\ge1$ and for each $x\in \Bbb R$, consider the following operator: $T_n: L^2(\Bbb R) \to L^p(\Bbb R) $ defined as
$$T_nf(x)=n^{3/4} \int_x^{x+1/n} f(t)\mathrm dt $$
The problem, as stated in the title, consists in finding for which $p\in[1,+\infty]$, $T_n$ is continuous.
The case $p=+\infty$ is ok, I'm having trouble in the other cases.
Since $T_n$ is linear, I have to prove that there is $K>0$ such that $\|T_nf\|_p\le K\|f\|_2$:
$$\|T_nf \|_p=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left|n^{3/4}\int_x^{x+1/n} f(t)\mathrm dt \right|^p\mathrm dx \right)^{1/p}=n^{3/4}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left|\int_x^{x+1/n} f(t)\mathrm dt \right|^p\mathrm dx \right)^{1/p} $$
Since I must have $\|f \|_2$, I tried to apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the inner integral but I get a divergent integral. I also tried to change coordinates (I was trying to do $p=1$ to see if I could generalize), noticing that I was integrating between the lines $t=x+1/n$ and $t=x$, but also  in this case I get a divergent intergral.

I solved similar exercises using Minkowsi's integral inequality, but here I don't know if it's applicable.

Comment: It may be helpful to nott that $T_nf$ is the convolution of $f$ with $n^{3/4} 1_{(-\frac 1  n, 0)}$

Comment: @geetha290krm 's comment provides a more conceptual reason for the result in my answer: $T_nf$ is the convolution of $f$ with a function in $L^q$ for all $q$. In particular, if we choose $q = \frac{1}{1/p+1/2}$, which is larger than or equal to $1$ when $2 \leq p \leq +\infty$, then Young's convolution inequality implies $||T_nf||_p \leq ||f||_2||n^{3/4}1_{(-1/n, 0)}||_q = n^{\frac{p-4}{4p}}||f||_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for all $p \geq 2$. I’ll first prove this for $p = 2$:

We have,

$$\begin{split}
||T_nf||_2^2 &= n^{\frac{3}{2}} \int_\mathbb{R} |\int_x^{x + 1/n} f(t) \, dt|^2 \, dx\\
&\leq n^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot n^{-2} \int_\mathbb{R} (n\int_x^{x + 1/n} |f(t)| \, dt)^2 \, dx\\
&\leq n^{-\frac{1}{2}} \int_\mathbb{R} n\int_x^{x + 1/n} |f(t)|^2 \, dt \, dx\\
&= n^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{t - 1/n}^t |f(t)|^2 \, dx \, dt\\
&= n^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot n^{-1} ||f||_2^2\\
&= n^{-\frac{1}{2}}||f||_2^2
\end{split}$$
Where the inequality on the third line uses Jensen’s inequality and the equality on the fourth line uses Fubini-Tonelli theorem. Thus, we have $||T_nf||_2 \leq n^{-\frac{1}{4}}||f||_2$.

You already mentioned the result for $p = +\infty$. For completeness, I’ll include a proof of that here as well: For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$\begin{split}
|T_nf(x)| &= n^{\frac{3}{4}} |\int_x^{x + 1/n} f(t) \, dt|\\
&\leq n^{\frac{3}{4}} \cdot n^{-\frac{1}{2}} ||f||_2\\
&= n^{\frac{1}{4}} ||f||_2
\end{split}$$
Where the inequality on the second line uses Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Hence, $||T_nf||_\infty \leq n^{\frac{1}{4}} ||f||_2$.

Now, for general $\infty > p \geq 2$. If $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, then,

$$\begin{split}
||g||_p^p &= \int_\mathbb{R} |g(x)|^p \, dx\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} |g(x)|^2 |g(x)|^{p - 2} \, dx\\
&\leq ||g||_\infty^{p - 2} ||g||_2^2
\end{split}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{split}
||T_nf||_p^p &\leq ||T_nf||_\infty^{p - 2} ||T_nf||_2^2\\
&\leq n^{\frac{p - 2}{4}} ||f||_2^{p - 2} \cdot n^{-\frac{1}{2}} ||f||_2^2\\
&= n^{\frac{p - 4}{4}} ||f||_2^p
\end{split}$$

So $||T_nf||_p \leq n^{\frac{p - 4}{4p}} ||f||_2$ for all $\infty > p \geq 2$. If we interpret $n^{\frac{p - 4}{4p}}$ as $n^{\frac{1}{4}}$ when $p = +\infty$, then the same holds when $p = +\infty$ as well, as we have already seen.

---

The following shows that the map is not bounded when $1 \leq p < 2$. In fact, the range is not even contained in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ when $1 \leq p < 2$.

For any $0 < \epsilon < 1$, let $f(t) = t^{-\frac{1 + \epsilon}{2}} 1_{\{t > 1\}}$. One easily checks that $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. When $x > 1$, we have,

$$\begin{split}
T_nf(x) &= n^{\frac{3}{4}} \cdot \frac{2}{1 - \epsilon}[(x+\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}} - x^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}}]\\
&= \frac{2n^{\frac{3}{4}}}{1 - \epsilon}x^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}}[(1+\frac{1}{nx})^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}} - 1]
\end{split}$$

By the generalized binomial theorem, as $x \to \infty$,

$$(1+\frac{1}{nx})^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}} - 1 \approx \frac{1-\epsilon}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{nx}$$

So, as $x \to \infty$,

$$\begin{split}
T_nf(x) &= \frac{2n^{\frac{3}{4}}}{1 - \epsilon}x^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}}[(1+\frac{1}{nx})^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}} - 1]\\
&\approx \frac{2n^{\frac{3}{4}}}{1 - \epsilon}x^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}} \cdot \frac{1-\epsilon}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{nx}\\
&= n^{-\frac{1}{4}}x^{-\frac{1+\epsilon}{2}}
\end{split}$$

But then, whenever $1 \leq p \leq \frac{2}{1+\epsilon}$, because we then have $-\frac{p+p\epsilon}{2} \geq -1$, so,

$$\begin{split}
||T_nf||_p^p &\geq ||1_{(1, \infty)}T_nf||_p^p\\
&\approx \int_1^\infty n^{-\frac{p}{4}}x^{-\frac{p+p\epsilon}{2}} \, dx\\
&= +\infty
\end{split}$$

As $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{2}{1+\epsilon} = 2$, this shows that the range of $T_n$ is not contained in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for all $n$ and $1 \leq p < 2$.